# Inserting data from vb.net and ms access

Tags: vb.net, ms-access

my problem is that i cannot insert data from vb.net using ms access.

I have this code so far:

```
Imports System.Data.OleDb
Public Class Form1
    Dim dbconn As New OleDbConnection
    Dim adt As New OleDbDataAdapter
    Dim ds As New DataSet
    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        dbconn.ConnectionString = "Provider=microsoft.jet.oledb.4.0;data source= Dat.laccdb"
    End Sub

    Private Sub Label2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Label2.Click

    End Sub

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        adt = New OleDbDataAdapter("insert into Dat (Surname,Email,Address,Contact) values ('" & TextBox1.Text & "','" & TextBox2.Text & "','" & TextBox3.Text & "','" & TextBox4.Text & "' )", dbconn)
        adt.Fill(ds)
        ds = New DataSet
        MsgBox("Saved")
    End Sub
End Class
```

this is the error i"am getting:

> {"Could not find file 'C:\Users\Admin\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\Dat\Dat\bin\Debug\Dat.laccdb'."}

Comment: the error says VS can't find the file in the given filepath.

Comment: Better learn to use parameters real quick.  Your error is pretty self describing.

Comment: The error message seems clear enough - that file cannot be found in that folder.  Please read [ask] and take the [tour]  (plus what Lars said)

Comment: Usually Access database from version 2005 onwards have the extension ACCDB but you have typed .LACCDB. This seems to be a typo

Comment: Also an ACCDB database requires the _Microsoft.ACE.OleDB.12.0_ not the Jet.4.0

Comment: steve this is how it came by itself i just copied it and paste

Comment: Your connection string has it: `data source= Dat.laccdb`.  The "L" looks suspicious, no?  Also, you assume a file path of where the executable is.

Comment: Take a second to digest what you are being told - your code is (trying to) insert ***whatever the user typed*** into those Text controls.  That is bad.  Very Bad.  Like Crossing the Streams level bad.  Read up on SQL Parameters and change that code (along with working out the file location/name etc).  Also also read [ask] and take the [tour]

Comment: you are not specifying a path to your database file...so its trying to find a file in your local application directory...there's other issues (like the SQL injection one mentioned above)...but thats the reason for the error

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
dbconn.ConnectionString = "Provider=microsoft.jet.oledb.4.0;data source= Dat.accdb"
```

Make sure Data file extension.

```
----update----

dbconn.ConnectionString="Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" & Application.StartupPath & "\Dat.accdb"
```

Make sure your database name is `Dat.accdb`, and put it together with the `exe` program.

Comment: And when your suggestion that should be a comment fails (it will fail), what should the OP do?

Answer (score 0):

```
Imports System.Data.OleDb
Public Class Form1
    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Dim sqlconn As New OleDb.OleDbConnection
        Dim sqlquery As New OleDb.OleDbCommand
        Dim connString As String
        connString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\Users\My PC\Documents\Database6.accdb"
        sqlconn.ConnectionString = connString
        sqlquery.Connection = sqlconn
        sqlconn.Open()
        sqlquery.CommandText = "INSERT INTO Table1(ID,Name) VALUES  (@ID,@Name)"
        sqlquery.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID", TextBox1.Text)
        sqlquery.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", TextBox2.Text)
        sqlquery.ExecuteNonQuery()
        sqlconn.Close()
        MsgBox("success")
    End Sub
End Class
```